# App is not updated in the emulator (android studio)

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

i often open my app on my mobile (transferring the apk to my mobile). But now i wanna use the emu so i can see the logcat because there is an error, but the problem the app is not updated. I made every thing possible to do. I re built it, cleared it, pressed on "Clear and rerun", made everything and still the same.. 
so anyone help me please because i need to know the error!!..

Thanks in advance.. 
if anyone wants to be more helpful (appreciable), here is my skype: mohamed.mahran220 so u can chat with me and help me faster!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new emulator with different system image, For example:

```
Nexus S - Marshmallow API 23.
```

if this didn't work, try deleting your .AndroidStudio2.x Folder.

Comment: But is there any another solution because i'm downloading marshmallow, now??

Comment: Copy your .AndroidStudio2.x Folder to another place, then delete it and try agian.

Comment: i copied the 2 folders to the desktop then deleted, was that what you meant?

Comment: Anyways, 5 mins left for the download to finish, thanks for helping

Comment: yeah, start android studio and create a new emulator then try running again, Ok.

Comment: Wtf what is that luck.. it is not in the new emu (the app) xDD, how to install it ?

Comment: make sure your emulator is running and go to this directory `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools` then **Shift + Right-click** choose **Open Command Windows here**, write `adb install apkDirectory\YourApp.apk`

Comment: What is "apkDirectory"?

Comment: Lol, it worked first time then i edited the app, it is not updated so i uninstalled and tried the same thing didn't work.. what is apkDirectory? i wrote the path of where the folder of the app is saved and then the apk which is in app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug but it tells me wrong path..

Comment: I mean the full path to your apk file + **\filename.apk**